# Dot placeholder functionality of tidiverse in magrittr in Python in general and Pandas in particular

Tags: python, r, pandas

As I am moving from R to Pandas i was wondering if Python had the same functionality as the placeholder dot in R's tidiverse. (that is referring to what is about to be defined) I have tried looking in the documentation but haven't found it. If so, what would be the best coding practice to get closer to that? What is the technical name to what this achieves in coding? (forward reference?)

From Magrittr documentation:

> Using the dot-place holder as lhs
>
> When the dot is used as lhs, the result will be a functional sequence, i.e. a function which applies the entire chain of right-hand sides in turn to its input. See the examples.

```
trig_fest <- . %>% tan %>% cos %>% sin

1:10 %>% trig_fest
#>  [1]  0.0133878 -0.5449592  0.8359477  0.3906486 -0.8257855  0.8180174
#>  [7]  0.6001744  0.7640323  0.7829771  0.7153150
trig_fest(1:10)
#>  [1]  0.0133878 -0.5449592  0.8359477  0.3906486 -0.8257855  0.8180174
#>  [7]  0.6001744  0.7640323  0.7829771  0.7153150
```

https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: Define a function? Like `np.sin(np.cos(np.tan(x)))`?